# Get uploaded file on submit button C# MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I can able to upload file on on-change of input file
without using HTML helper class.but I need to read and get data of uploaded text file on submit button.

Below code which I am using in html :

```
<div>
   <input id="uploadtxtfile" type="file" multiple />
   <button type="submit" class="btn-sm" id="btnuploadfile"/>                         
</div>
```

and jquery code in which I am calling:

```
$('#uploadtxtfile').change(function (e) {
    var i = 0;
    var files = $("#uploadtxtfile").get(0).files;
    fileData = new FormData();      
    for (i; i < files.length; i++) {
        var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
        fileData.append(fileName, files[i]);
        $("#txtUpload").val(fileName);         
    }       
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ViewProcessEDI/UploadTextFile",
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: fileData,
        success: function (res) {
            if (res.Message == "Success") {
                divListProcessEDI($("#currentPage").val());
                popup.close();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    Message('Success!', 'TextFile Upload Successfully!', 's');
                }, 100);
            }
            else {
                Message('Error!', res.Message, 'e');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and Controller function is:

How can I get uploaded files on submit button.Can anyone please guide me on this.

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> UploadTextFile()
    {
        string ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
        Dictionary<string, string> returnVal = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        try
        {
            CredentialsMaster objCredentialsMaster = new CredentialsMaster();
            if (CheckSession.CheckStoreOwnerSession(ref objCredentialsMaster))
            {
                if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
                {
                    HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
                    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                    {
                        HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];
                        string fname;
                        // Checking for Internet Explorer  
                        if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
                        {
                            string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                            fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fname = file.FileName;
                        }
                        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            // Get the complete folder path and store the file inside it.  
                            file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(@"E:\EDITextFiles", fname));                               
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Session Expired";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json("Upload failed");
        }           
        return Json("File Uploaded Successfully");
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you try looking in the internet for an answer? you can start in [this link](https://www.aurigma.com/upload-suite/developers/aspnet-mvc/how-to-upload-files-in-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: Yes I went through links, but I need to do it without using HTML helper class in MVC

Comment: So please describe your setup and limitation and add a code snippet so we can better understand your context

Answer (score 0):

I got answer which I need to get from following post:
[passing file to controller without using form,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227722/passing-file-to-controller-without-using-form)

in which I need to pass posted filename as jQuery("#file").get(0).files[0] in javascript so that I can get posted file name in controller function.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of your question is how to do this without @HTML helpers.  You can always do things without those helpers by using a form element and calling to the action.  @HTML helpers just assist in the creation of HTML5 elements.  The form element would allow a call to the controller without the need of using Ajax should you ever need to do so.

[html form posting to mvc controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697283/html-form-posting-to-mvc-controller)